# CMake to build shared object .so files in linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cmake

Task -> Run Cmake to generate dll in windows and shared object(.so files) in linux.

I am porting code from windows to linux . I have made the required changes in source code. I have tried changing the CMakeLists.txt files but when I tried to do make it complains of "Cannot find source files". May you guys please point me out where I am making mistake. CMakeList.txt is shown below.
The cmake runs fine in windows but in linux it complains about the error.
    I have commented few lines and added line in CMakeLIsts.txt to make it work in Linux but it doesn't work.

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 2.8 )
CMAKE_POLICY( SET CMP0017 NEW ) 

PROJECT( disk_space_model )
INCLUDE( ../libs/helper_functions.cmake )
INCLUDE_THIRD_PARTY_SFC()

SET(    HEADER_FILES 
        stdafx.h
        INS_sensor_model.h
)

SET(    SOURCE_FILES
        Disk_space_model.cpp
)

SET(    RESOURCE_FILES 
        "Disk Space DLL.rc"
        resource.h
)

COMMON_SETUP()
SETUP_Lab_LIB_FILES( lib_foo lib_boo_files lib_platform lib_utils )

#ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_USRDLL -DINSSENSORDLL_EXPORTS)
#ADD_LIBRARY( disk_space_model SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${RESOURCE_FILES} ${CMAKE_HELPER_FILES} )
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--export-all-symbols")
ADD_LIBRARY( disk_space_model [ STATIC | SHARED ] ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${RESOURCE_FILES}  ${CMAKE_HELPER_FILES} )
SET_OUTPUT_DIRS( disk_space_model )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( disk_space_model ${LIB_FILES} )
```

Below are the following errors that I have received when I do make after congiure and generate on CMake-gui

```
  4 bit compiler
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:37 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  Cannot find source file:

    [

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Cannot find source file:

    STATIC

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Cannot find source file:

    |

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Cannot find source file:

    SHARED

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Cannot find source file:

    ]

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


-- Build files have been written to: /home/mydir/svn/proj1/apps/disk space
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

Comment: Which source files can it "not find?" Also, are you sure you want to override `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` like this? Or just add to them? And if that's your actual syntax, it's erroneous: the commented line is OK, but `[ STATIC | SHARED ]` is **not** valid.

Comment: @Angew, Thanks for replying . Well I have added my error message in my question area. Issue 2) You have mentioned but [ STATIC | SHARED ] is not valid but thats what i have found on google to create .so files in linux. If this step is wrongcould you please point out why it is wrong and what will be correct one? Thanks

Comment: It's metasyntax. It means "either put `STATIC` (for generating a static library) or `SHARED` (for generating a shared library) in there." And that's the errors you're getting. It's looking for files named `[`, `STATIC` etc. (since the keyword `STATIC` or `SHARED`, if present, must be the *first argument* after library name). Just use the line you commented out and you should be fine.

Comment: That's an option list. Everything in `[]` is optional, each valid option is separated by `|`. So, it is either `STATIC` or `SHARED`. By the way, if you read the CMake docs, you'll also see that there's a `MODULE` option for plugin libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's broken because of this:

```
ADD_LIBRARY( disk_space_model [ STATIC | SHARED ] ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${RESOURCE_FILES}  ${CMAKE_HELPER_FILES} )
```

I guess you copy-pasted `[ STATIC | SHARED ]` from the documentation.  That's supposed to be a choice of either `STATIC` or `SHARED` (the latter, in your case).

Comment: I have  added that line because when i Tried jsut with one option it complains of  missing files.  for example                       c++: error: foo: No such file or directory
c++: error: DLL: No such file or directory  While if I tried to build it in windows. it works flawlessly.

Comment: You also should not include HEADER_FILES in ADD_LIBRARY.  It doesn't make sense: source (implementation) files are what you build in C++, not headers.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Not true. In CMakeLists, you normally list your header files in `add_library()`/`add_executable()` calls, so that they show up in the project file list in Visual Studio and other IDEs. Still they will not be compiled.

Comment: I see.  Apparently sort of a CMake "bug" or missing feature, and one I never knew about because I never used CMake with Visual Studio.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Out of curiosity, how is this a "bug?" A CMakeList is not a Makefile - the arguments to `add_library()` are "files which are part of the library," not (just) "source files to be compiled to make the library." IMO, it's the semantics of the command, not a "bug."

Comment: Well it's a documentation bug at least, because the CMake official manual says that add_library() takes a list of "source" files with no mention of header files that I can see.